# Is there any ranking of countries based on per-capita expenditure in R&D?

Tags: gdp

All the rankings available on the internet are "R&D expenditure by % of GDP".

Is there any ranking of countries based on per-capita expenditure in R&D?

Comment: Can't you just calculate the per capita R&D expenditure from R&D spending as a % of GDP? Data on population size are readily available online these days.

Comment: You can sort the following table by either per capita R&D spending or % of GDP:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_research_and_development_spending

It's wikipedia, but I spot checked some of the sources and they look credible - I'd think as a % of GDP would be more interesting than per capita, because per capita will be influenced by GDP per capita.

Comment: I think the most credible source would be either World Bank's (https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GB.XPD.RSDV.GD.ZS?year_high_desc=true) or OECD's (https://data.oecd.org/rd/gross-domestic-spending-on-r-d.htm) data. It's all % of GDP, but with little work you should get what you want.